# I am stuck with copying a class given an address, I am segfaulting

Tags: c++, function, class, pointers

I have struggled with it for a while but I really can't get it, I am just getting segfaults. I am trying to copy a class, the function I am writing to copy is also below. Crossed out are combinations that I have tried in vain, it's time to call for help

```
class Scene
{  private:
int max;
   int* x_row, *y_col;          // maximum and min coordinates of each image
   Image**image_layers;
}


void Scene::_copy(const Scene &source)                                        
{
max = source.max;                    
x_row = new int[source.x_row];
y_col = new int[source.y_col];
image_layers = new Image*[source.max]; 

for(int i = 0; i < source.max; i++)
{
    if(source.image_layers[i] != NULL)
    {
        //image_layers[i] = new Image(*(source.image_layers[i]));  
        // image_layers[i] = new Image;
        //*image_layers[i] = *source.image_layers[i];


        // image_layers[i] = source.image_layers[i]; 

    }
    else
    {   
        image_layers[i] = NULL;
    }
    x_row[i] = source.x_row[i];
    y_col[i] = source.y_col[i];


}
```

EDIT:

I forgot to say that this function is called as  " scene(*set) "

Comment: Is it C++? Add the language tag.

Comment: yes, it is c++ language

Comment: Aren't you remotely curious what happens to the data that `x_row`, `y_col`, and `image_layers` in the *target* object (`*this`) references upon invoking this thing, or are you just ok with the ensuing memory leak. And this: `image_layers[i] = source.image_layers[i]` doesn't copy anything except a pointer (and leaks the allocation immediately prior in the process). When this is done you'll have two objects holding a pointer to the same Image.

Comment: my professor doesn't like memory leaks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The segfault happens here or because of this:

```
x_row = new int[source.x_row];
y_col = new int[source.y_col];
```

On the right hand side, you use the address `source.x_row` as an array size. This is a very large number that most likely will cause the allocation to fail.
You need to keep a member for holding the size or better yet use a `std::vector<int>` object instead.

Copying C arrays are done faster with memcpy. With C++ vectors, you can just assign one to the other:

```
x_row = source.x_row
```

Nothing to do with the question, but this function should be named `operator=`, will make using the class easier by assigning one instance to another:

```
Scene & Scene::operator=(const Scene &source)                                        
{
    // copy elements
    ...

    return *this;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
x_row = new int[source.x_row];
y_col = new int[source.y_col];
```

Are you sure about above code?
`source.x_row` is pointer

Comment: it is because its a scene object